# Generic Table Definitions with Column[T] with Slick

Tags: scala, generics, slick

We have recently done some refactoring on our slick code to make it generic, and in the process we have made Generic Tables (which are `abstract classes` that extend `Table`). An issue however arises when we try to make a generic table with a `Column[T]` as shown below

NOTE: The following code doesn't compile, this is just attempting to show what I am doing

```
abstract class SomeTable[T :BaseTypedType,C](tag:Tag,name:String)(implicit mappedTypeMapperEvidence:BaseColumnType[T], longEvidence T <:< Long) extends Table[C](tag,name) {
   def someColumn:Column[T]
}
```

Lets assume we define some table as follows

```
class MyTable(tag:Tag) extends SomeTable[UserId,TestClass](tag,"my_table") {
   def someColumn = column[UserId]("user_id")
}
```

And we have `UserId` defined as follows

```
case class UserId(l:Long) extends AnyVal
```

Now we already have a `MappedColumnType` for this `UserId`, i.e.

```
  implicit val userIdType = MappedColumnType.base[UserId,Long]
     (_.id,UserId)
```

The issue is, you seem to be unable to make slick, using the `BaseTypeType` (created by the `MappedColumnType.base`), to infer the type of `Column[T]`

In the above case, and the end result of what I am trying to do (write a generic query), we might write something like this.

```
def someGenericQuery[C,T<:SomeTable[T]](c:Query[T,C,Seq]) = {
   c.filter(_.someColumn === 1l)
}
```

Is something like this possible in slick? Unfortunately I can't use nominal typing (i.e. making my `UserId` extend another class/trait) because Value classes disallow that (they can't be extended or extend anything), so there doesn't seem to be any way to reveal the inner type of the value class (in this case Long) in a generic way

Comment: What is the exact compile-time error you get? I am surprised this doesn't work.

Comment: And why do you use `<:<` instead of `<:`?

Comment: The error you get is `Cannot prove that UserId <:< Long`. Although you can use <: (I.e. F <: Long), that also generates a compile error (type arguments do not confirm)

I think the main issue is that, you cant really use nominal typing with value classes, because they are final and they cant extend anything (nor can they can be extended), and because there doesn't seem to be any way to get an implicit view from a value class to its underlying type, I can't actually unwrap the long